# How to make UITableView updating with delegate and datasource even if the view controller is a "child" controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, subview

I have two view controllers, let's call X, and Y. the X has a UIView called "container". the Y has a UIButton and UITableView with the delegate and datasource set to Y. After I initialise the Y view inside X, the X's container do `container.addSubView (Y.view)`. The button and tableview is shown, but the table view does not have any content at all. When I add break point, the `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` functions are not called at all. But if I open the Y view controller directly, the table view updates properly. Why is this happen? And how to fix it? Thanks.

EDIT: The code.

```
class Util: NSObject {
    static func getViewControllerID(vcname: String, fromStoryboard storyboardName: String = "Main") -> UIViewController {
        return UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(vcname)
    }
}

class X : UIViewController {

    var tabs = [UIView]();
    var tabIdx = 1;
    var views = [UIView]();
    @IBOutlet var container : UIView!;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();

        for i in 1...4 {
            let tab = self.view.viewWithTag(i)!;
            tab.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor();
            tabs.append(tab);
        }

        views.append(Util.getViewControllerID("Dummy").view);
        views.append(Util.getViewControllerID("Dummy").view);
        views.append(Util.getViewControllerID("Y").view);
        views.append(Util.getViewControllerID("Dummy").view);

        changeActiveTab(0);
    }

    func changeActiveTab (idx : Int) {
        tabIdx = idx;
        for tab in tabs { tab.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor(); }
        tabs[idx].backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "41C7DB");
        for view in views { view.removeFromSuperview(); }
        let view = views[idx];
        view.frame = container.bounds;
        container.addSubview(view);
    }

    @IBAction func tabTapped (sender: AnyObject) {
        let btn = sender as! UIButton;
        let idx = btn.tag - 11;
        changeActiveTab(idx);
    }
}


class Y : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var dummyData = [String]();

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for i in 101...106 {
            let btn = self.view.viewWithTag(i)! as! UIButton;
            btn.makeViewRoundedRectWithCornerRadius(4);
        }

        dummyData.append("a");
        dummyData.append("b");
        dummyData.append("c");
        dummyData.append("d");
        dummyData.append("e");
        dummyData.append("f");
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")!;

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor();
        var lbl = [UILabel]();
        for i in 1...6 { lbl.append(cell.viewWithTag(i)! as! UILabel); }
        for i in 0...5 { lbl[i].text = dummyData[i]; }

        return cell;
    }

}
```

Comment: @user3182143 done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add your `childViewController` as a `subview`

```
container.addSubview(view);
```

You also need move your `childViewController` to parent. Try to add this lines of code

```
self.addChildViewController(childViewController)
childViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

And don't forget when you remove it from superView, just call

```
childViewController.removeFromParentViewController()
```

Comment: Sorry, after I asked here and asked my coworkers, I realised that I only hold the "view", but not the viewcontroller itself. So when the view tried to update the tableview, the viewcontroller was already gone. So now I've changed the code to include the parent viewcontroller of each of the view, and it works properly. Thanks!

Comment: But your code also add some knowledge to me, so thanks for answering! :D

Comment: You are welcome!) So if your question answered, please mark it as answered.